# Vertically-repeating horizontal gradient in CSS

Tags: css, gradient

I'm having trouble coming up with a pure CSS mechanism to get a particular background pattern happening.

What I'm looking for is a horizontal gradient that is also repeated vertically, with a gap between each instance. Example:

[image: Bidirectional Repeat Gradient]
<sub>(source: [howsfamily.net](http://howsfamily.net/bidirectional-repeating-gradient.png))</sub>

I can get the horizontal effect easily enough

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, white, red, white); background-size: 100% 50px; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

I can get the vertical effect (without the horizontal gradient)

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0px, red 50px, transparent 50px, transparent 100%); background-size: 100% 150px; background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Does anyone know how to combine the two?

Comment: Since you're already going for `linear-gradient`, I would suggest using an SVG as a background.

Comment: Example using SVG: http://dabblet.com/gist/6632969

Comment: Great idea; haven't dipped my toes in the SVG pool before, so it didn't leap to mind. Looks to have solved the problem though.

Do you want to repost that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

Since you're already going for [`linear-gradient`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients), I would suggest using an [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css) for more freedom and better compatibility.

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/6632969

The SVG that is used (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="10" height="100" viewBox="0 0 10 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="l">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="red" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="50" fill="url(#l)" />
</svg>
```

You can tweak the `height` and `viewBox` here and `background-size` in CSS to fit your need.

The [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute here is crucial, otherwise the background image may not stretch.