# CSS - Vertical Border with Horizontal Gradients

Tags: css

I have a nifty vertical divider that has a horizontal gradient for certain parts of my page, and it works splendidly. This is just an image file that I apply as a centered background to a layer and float it there to get the effect I want.

[image: Image Example Here]

This works great, but I was wanting to try and do this to a table cell border, so that it cut down that side and gave the slight gradient effect all the way down. Is this possible with CSS3?

I have explored [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908211/vertically-repeating-horizontal-gradient-in-css) a bit, and it does seem like this technique is feasible, but attempting to just add these gradients to the `border` property keeps coming up with failures.

Is there a specific technique involved in such an effect?

### Update

Small jsFiddle to demonstrate how the current divider works, and where I am trying to apply it in a normal table and what keeps happening when I try.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/u2Tgq/)

Comment: Can you add some code or create a jsFiddle please?

Comment: Sure, this is essentially a sample of how the current divider works, and I've put a small table on there to show where I am trying to get this effect to happen, and what keeps happening when I try it. :http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/u2Tgq/

Comment: Not sure if the effect can be done on table borders. Can you wrap the table in a div and use pseudo-elements for the bordering? Like this: http://jsbin.com/afadIbE/2/

Comment: Why yes, actually. That works wonderfully well too. I will try this! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending from the comments above...
This effect can be mimicked by using pseudo-elements on a container div. I think in your case, it may be better than trying to implement on a table border. For example, a wrapper div called 'box' or whatever class name you prefer...

```
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: -10px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #333 0%, transparent 100%);
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/afadIbE/2/). 
Also don't forget to add your vendor prefixes on `background: linear-gradient` in order to make it cross-browser.